# preg_replace same words in a string

Tags: php, regex

String: this is text :wall: :wall: :wall: :wall: more text

Output should be: this is text :wall: more text

Task: Reduce the word :wall: to only 1.

I tried these both ideas, but didn't work:

```
$post_message = preg_replace("/([\:wall:])+/", "\\1", $post_message);

$post_message = preg_replace('/:wall:/', '', $post_message, 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below regex in `preg_replace` function.

**Regex:**

```
(:wall:)(?:\s+:wall:)+
```

OR

```
(:wall:)(?:\s+\1)+
```

**Replacement string:**

```
$1
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/61)

**Code:**

```
<?php
$str = "this is text :wall: :wall: :wall: :wall: more text";
echo preg_replace('~(:wall:)(?:\s+\1)+~', '$1', $str);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
this is text :wall: more text
```

`(:wall:)` Captures the text `:wall:` into a group. This could be referred by group index 1.  So this `(?:\s+\1)+` matches the folowing one or more space + `:wall:` strings. Replacing the match with the chars inside group index 1 will remove all the duplicate `:wall:` strings.

Comment: would you please show me the final code? This didnt work:

    $post_subject = preg_replace("(:wall:)(?:\s+:wall:)+", "\\1", $post_subject);

Comment: you forget to add the delimiters. it wouldn't be `"(:wall:)(?:\s+:wall:)+"`, it would be `"~(:wall:)(?:\s+:wall:)+~"`

Answer (score 0):

```
(:wall:)(?=((?!\1).)*\1)
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/62

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'this is text :wall: :wall: :wall: :wall: more text';
$post_message = preg_replace("#(:wall:\s+)+#i", '\1', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Accordingliy to the top solution:

I need:

String1: this is text :( :( :( more text

String2: this is text :? :? :? more text

Output should be: this is text :( more text

Output should be: this is text :? more text

Task: Reduce the smilie :( to only 1.

Task: Reduce the smilie :? to only 1.

I tried these, but didn't work:

```
$post_message = preg_replace('~(:()(?:\s+\1)+~', '$1', $post_message);

$post_message = preg_replace('~(:?)(?:\s+\1)+~', '$1', $post_message);
```

Thanks again.